# Unable to activate virtual environment on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I am using virtualenv to create a virtual environment. I am able to activate the virtual environment on the command prompt but when i try to do the same on visual studio code , it says "Could not find conda environment: Test
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.".

It is trying to find a anaconda environment inspite of me using a global python interpreter.

When I use "activate env_name", how do i make it to search and activate a virtual environment outside anaconda. I am using windows 10.

[image: The Selected python interpreter and the error].

Comment: hope this helps: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/efficient-way-to-activate-conda-in-vscode-ef21c4c231f2

Comment: The article didn't help me but i could activate the environment using ". ./env_name/scripts/activate.ps1"